# Why it doesn't work when I use MysqlConnection.open()?

Tags: c#, mysql

```
  using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;


namespace dbTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        string sqlStr   = "Database=weather;Server=127.0.0.1;Uid=root;Password=123456;pooling=false;CharSet=UTF8;port=3306";

          MySqlConnection mysql = new MySqlConnection(sqlStr);

             mysql.Open();

             Console.WriteLine("SUCCESS");

              mysql.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

It will crash when running the sentence "mysql.Open()"

does anybody know why?
the error message is:
        -unhandled exception:System.Collecions.Generic.KeyNotFoundException:the key is not in the dictionary
        -in System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'2.get_Item(TKEY KEY)
        -in Mysql.Data.MySqlClient.CharSetMap.GetCharacterSet(DBVersion version,String CHARSETNAME)
        -in Mysql.Data.MySqlClient.CharSetMap.GetEncoding(DVversion version,String CharSetName)
        -in Mysql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Configure(MySqlConnection connection)
        -in Mysql.Data.MySqlClient.Mysqlconnection.Open()
        -in dbTest.Program.Main(String[] args) location:blahblah...

Comment: `KeyNotFoundException`? Are you sure this exception comes from somewhere else?

Comment: I don't know why it happens.

Comment: Presumably because a key isn't in a dictionary.  Perhaps you could share the entire error (including the stack trace), or should we just guess?

Comment: "unhandled exception:System.Collecions.Generic.KeyNotFoundException:the key is not in the dictionary" will be shown in the console window..

Comment: Read @David's entire comment. Update your question to show the complete stack trace of that exception.

Comment: wrap it in a try catch to try to get the actual exception message.

Answer (score 4):

You're specifying an invalid character set.  Take a look at [this reference](https://connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-net-mysqlconnection/specifying-character-set/):

> Note! Use lower case value utf8 and not upper case UTF8 as this will fail.

The value is case-sensitive and should be lowercase:

```
Database=weather;Server=127.0.0.1;Uid=root;Password=123456;pooling=false;CharSet=utf8;port=3306
```

Admittedly it's an unhelpful error message, but it is what it is I suppose.  (This is why reading a stack trace can often be more helpful than the message itself, since it can provide a basis for researching the answer.)

Comment: After checking the check mark: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267818/stack-overflow-helped-me-with-my-problem-on-which-network-can-i-share-my-succes.