# Unity3D connection to MySQL error

Tags: c#, mysql, dictionary, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

I'm trying to get Unity client to establish connection to MySQL server purely for reads. I get an error when the connection is being made.

My Code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using MySql.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

public class DatabaseHandler : MonoBehaviour {

    public string host, database, user, password;
    public bool pooling = true;

    private string connectionString;
    private MySqlConnection con = null;
    private MySqlCommand cmd = null;
    private MySqlDataReader rdr = null;

    private MD5 _md5Hash;

    void Awake() {

        DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
        connectionString = "Server="+host+";Database="+database+";User ID="+user+";Password="+password+";Pooling=";
        if (pooling){
            connectionString += "true;";
        } else {
            connectionString += "false;";
        }

        try {
            con = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
            con.Open(); //  THIS is line 47 in the error
            Debug.Log ("Mysql State: " + con.State);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Debug.Log (e); //  THIS is line 51 in the error
        }

    }
}
```

Error:

> System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not
>   present in the dictionary.   at
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,MySql.Data.MySqlClient.CharacterSet].get_Item
>   (System.String key) [0x000a2] in
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Generic/Dictionary.cs:150
>   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.CharSetMap.GetCharacterSet (DBVersion
>   version, System.String CharSetName) [0x00000] in :0 
>   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.CharSetMap.GetEncoding (DBVersion version,
>   System.String CharSetName) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Configure
>   (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection connection) [0x00000] in
>   :0    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open
>   () [0x00000] in :0    at (wrapper
>   remoting-invoke-with-check)
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection:Open ()   at
>   DatabaseHandler.Awake () [0x0007a] in /Users/ThaMacPro/Desktop/Unity
>   Projects/youtubeMySQL/Assets/Scripts/DatabaseHandler.cs:47 
>   UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object) DatabaseHandler:Awake() (at
>   Assets/Scripts/DatabaseHandler.cs:51)

Can anyone tell me how this error can be fixed?

Thank you!

Comment: looks like you are providing an invalid connection string; forget about unity, try googling for this specific mysql error.

Comment: Thank you @Roberto, after searching for more specific keywords, I came upon this which solved it.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25933522/why-it-doesnt-work-when-i-use-mysqlconnection-open

Comment: Would you like to provide that link as the answer? I'll mark it as the answer @Roberto

Comment: haha that's the answer I googled to make that comment, but I didn't mention UTF because I didn't think that was the problem. Anyway, I think it's fair that you write the answer and mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: [Why it doesn't work when I use MysqlConnection.open()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25933522/why-it-doesnt-work-when-i-use-mysqlconnection-open)

Had to add the charset to the connnectionString.

Thank you @Roberto! :-)

Comment: I was encountering more issues with the same kind of error that most people were not encountering, so I ended up using a different host (rackspace) for my MySQL database. No more issues.